# Android issue with ListView inside Fragments

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview, android-asynctask

I want to load some schedule data from Json using AsyncTask and put them to a listview. 
The problem starts because i need to display more than one schedule/listview. I need to display schedules from different dates. So I decide to use fragment using ViewPagerIndicator.

Like this image

[image]

The real problem is, sometimes the data getting mixed/swapped from one fragment to another. Here's the flow :

1. When activity created, 3(three) fragments fetch schedule at a same time (AsyncTask). Let say "Yesterday", "Today" and "Tomorrow" fragment.
2. "Today" schedule's finished first. I put them to listview and it's successfully displayed.
3. But then "Tomorrow" or "Yesterday" schedule got finished too. And i dont know why, the listview in "Today" fragment now displaying "Tomorrow" schedule.
4. And if "Tomorrow" or "Yesterday" failed to fetch the schedule, listview in "Today" disappeared.

I dont know what really happened to my listview.

Here's my code :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (container == null) {
        return null;
    }
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.schedule_result_fragment, container, false);
    initViews();
    if(scheduleList == null || scheduleList.size()<=0){
        executeScheduleAsyncTask();
    }else{
        adapter = new ScheduleListAdapter(getActivity(), scheduleList, 1);
        lstSchedule.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    return view;
}


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public void executeScheduleAsyncTask(){
    GetScheduleFromServer getScheduleFromServer = new GetScheduleFromServer();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        getScheduleFromServer.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, null,null,null);
    else
        getScheduleFromServer.execute(null,null,null);
}


public class GetScheduleFromServer extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject>{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        showLoading();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
        String url = "";
        url = getString(R.string.url_schedule);
        url = url.replace(" ", "%20");

        //Creating JSON Parser instance
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(); 
        try{
            json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            json = null;
            e.printStackTrace();
        return json;
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        super.onPostExecute(json);
        if(json!=null){
            try {
                String jsonStatus = "";
                try{
                    jsonStatus = json.getString(TAG_STATUS);
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    jsonStatus = null;
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if(jsonStatus != null){
                    //JSON SUCCESS
                    if(jsonStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("0")){
                        JSONArray schedules = json.getJSONArray(TAG_SCHEDULE);
                        if(schedules!=null && schedules.length()>0){
                            scheduleList = new ArrayList<Schedule>();
                            for(int i = 0; i < schedules.length(); i++){
                                scheduleList.add(schedule);
                            }

                            // IF JSON HAS A SCHEDULE
                            if(scheduleList.size()>0){
                                adapter = new ScheduleListAdapter(getActivity(), scheduleList, 1);
                                lstSchedule.setAdapter(adapter);
                            }

                            // IF JSON DOESNT HAS A SCHEDULE
                            else{
                                txvWarningTitle.setText(getString(R.string.no_results));
                                txvWarningDescription.setText(getString(R.string.no_schedules));
                                adapter = new ScheduleListAdapter(getActivity(), scheduleList, 1);
                                lstSchedule.setAdapter(adapter);
                            }
                        }
                    }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
            }
        }


        hideLoading();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Is either `adapter` or `scheduleList` a static field in that fragment class?

Comment: hi thanks Luksprog, my scheduleList was static, after i remove the static ,it works fine. Thanks very much, you just saved my life